# Generación de Facturas - SAT

Tags: php

Qué tal amigos, últimamente me veo forzado en tener que generar facturas para clientes. Soy muy nuevo en este tema y quisiera poder crear un pequeño sistema a la medida para que pueda generar las facturas yo mismo. Desafortunadamente, no he encontrado mucha información acerca de este tema y mis preguntas son las siguientes:

> - ¿Qué necesito que tener para poder generar una factura? (PD. ya estoy registrado en SHCP)
> - ¿Cuál es el proceso a seguir para generarlas?
> - ¿Existe algún SDK de PHP para poder generar estas facturas?

Como último dato vivo en México, no se si en cada país sea diferente el proceso. Se que no tiene que ver mucho con la programación pero no supe en que otra comunidad de Stack Overflow pueda pertenecer esta pregunta. ¡Saludos y de ante mano gracias!

Comment: Buenas Cuando dices si existe algún SDK te refieres a una biblioteca o librería? Lo que preguntas es si existe alguna solución PHP para generación de facturas, sí que existen. Por ejemplo, la librería DOMPDF. Aquí te pongo un tutorial para integrarlo en tu aplicación: https://manuais.iessanclemente.net/index.php/Generación_de_PDF's_con_PHP_y_la_librería_DOMPDF#Configuraci.C3.B3n_de_la_librer.C3.ADa_DOMPDF Saludos!

Comment: Mi pregunta va más enfocada hacía como realizar en timbrado, retornar el XML, etc. No tanto hacia cómo generar un PDF. Con SDK, me refiero a alguna librería y/o clase que consuma el REST API del SAT (https://developer.corpfolder.com/sat-api/apis).

Comment: En cada país son diferentes las normas para emitir facturas. Debes especificar más la pregunta o aportar algún ejemplo de lo que esperas. Por otro lado por **SAT** no se realmente a que te refieres, para mi significa `Servicio de Atención Técnica` o `Sindicato Andaluz de Trabajadores`. Edita la pregunta y añade los datos relevantes para aclararla.

Comment: SAT - http://www.sat.gob.mx/Paginas/Inicio.aspx

Comment: Creo que mis 3 preguntas son bastante claras. No se cuál no entendiste muy bien...